# Count basic math operations

Tags: python

I would like to get a guess on the computaional effort of my algorithms, meaning in this case: **How often do I add, subtract, multiply and divide in my algorithm**.

Example:

```
def b(a):
    a = a + 3  #1
    a = a * a  #2
    a = a * -1 #3
    return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        b(1)
```

the ouput of the analysis should be:

1: + **-->** 1 mathmatical operation

2: * **-->** 1 mathmatical operation

3: +, - **-->** 2 mathmatical operations

for every loop, therefore the analyzer run on this program should return **40**.

Comment: Why not just count it up? Also, how do you know it's 40?

Comment: I think the example you mentioned is not what you really desire. If this is what you need, increment the `count` by `4` every time you call `b()`?

Comment: after every `a=a+3` put `adds=adds+1`,etc. and at the end `print(" + --->", adds)`

Comment: or create funtions `a=add(a,3)`, `a=mul(a, a)`, etc. which will count operations: `def add(x,y): global adds ; adds+=1 ; return x+y`

Comment: If it has to be more general, convert every operation in a string variable (not sure how to do this, so, maybe you have to put it twice, once as a string and once as a mathematical term). Then, in the end, you can use string operations to count the number of +, -, *, /.

Answer (score 1):

A Pythonic solution might be to create a class Operand, with associated operators +, -, *, /, specified with special methods (__add__, __radd__, __mult__, __rmult__, etc.). If you use the "__r" methods correctly you can start also including litterals (1, 2.0, 3.0) in pretty much any order, as long as there is one Operand.

The class would have a counter, set to zero at creation time. Each call adds 1, but also adds the counter of each operator (default = 0).

Then you could write:

```
a = Operand(2)
b = a+2-5
assert b.effort == 3
```

Then you can go ahead and calculate your effort:

```
a = Operand(5)
a = a + 3  #1
a = a * a  #2
a = a * -1 #3
print(a.effort)
```

In the first line, you create the object. In the second line, the result of a + 3 is 8, and the resulting object has an effort of 1 . In the third, it has an effort of 3 (1 + 1 for a + 1 for a). In the fourth, it has an effort of 4. Etc.

I haven't implemented and tested it, but it should work more or less according to those principles.

**Note about litterals:** a + 2 + 3 would give you a count of 3, but 2 + 3 + a might give you a count of 2 (since 5 is still an integer, and not an Operand). So perhaps you want to avoid the __r methods, to stay on the safe side... it depends.