# How to Subclassing ndarray to cumulatively record the number of addition operators?

Tags: python, numpy, class, subclassing

I am using Python and I am trying to construct a class, say `Numbers`, using [Subclassing ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html). I wish my class satisfies two following properties:

- All the methods of `numpy` is applicable to my class `Numbers`. (This is the reason why  I chose to use Subclassing ndarray.)
- Every times I perform the addition between two instances of class `Numbers`, I can cumulatively record the number of additions I have used.

Here is what I tried

```py
import numpy as np

class Numbers(np.ndarray):

    nb_add = 0

    def __new__(cls, values):
        self = np.asarray(values).view(cls)
        return self 

    def __add__(self, new_numbers):
        Numbers.nb_add += len(new_numbers)
        return self + new_numbers

a = Numbers([1,2,3,4])
b = Numbers([5,6,7,8])
c = a+b 
print(a.reshape(2, 2)) # expect [[1,2], [3,4]]
print(Numbers.nb_add)# expect 4 = number of addtions
```

But the method `__add__` leads to error.

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233550/count-basic-math-operations), but it is not the case I am looking for.

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the expression `self + new_numbers` is referencing the `__add__` method of Numbers and hence the method calls itself.
If you explicitly call the `__add__` method of the base class, then you get the result you want:

```
import numpy as np

class Numbers(np.ndarray):

    nb_add = 0

    def __new__(cls, values):
        self = np.asarray(values).view(cls)
        return self

    def __add__(self, new_numbers):
        Numbers.nb_add += len(new_numbers)
        return np.ndarray.__add__(self,new_numbers)

a = Numbers([1,2,3,4])
b = Numbers([5,6,7,8])
c = a+b 
print(a.reshape(2, 2)) # expect [[1,2], [3,4]]
print(Numbers.nb_add)# expect 4 = number of addtions
```

Comment: this is indeed amazing, thank you so much!!!